# DB接続とデータ出力の記述をPHP5→PHP7対応する記述へ

Tags: php

お世話になります。下記の記述では、PHP7環境でエラーが出ます。
どのように変更すれば良いのかを教えていただけましたら、助かります。

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("XXXXXXX","user","password", "DBname");
if (!$connect) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
mysqli_set_charset($connect, 'utf8');


$notice_query = "SELECT * FROM NoticeTable WHERE type !='B' ORDER BY serialnum DESC";
$notice_result = $connect->query($notice_query);
if(!$notice_result) {
    echo "<script>
    window.alert(\"DB接続エラーです！\") 
    history.go(-1) 
    </script>";
    exit;
}
if(!$total) {
    echo "データなし";
}
$serialnumber = $total - $LineNumber*($page-1);
for($i = $first; $i <= $last; $i++) {
    foreach ($notice_result as $notice_row) {
        $NoticeSerialNum = $notice_row['serialnum'];
        $NoticeTitle = $notice_row['noticetitle'];
        $Noticeinputdate = $notice_row['inputdate'];
        $Noticeinputdate=substr($Noticeinputdate, 0, 10);
…
```

追記です。。。
PHPエラー文が表示されるのではなく、データ表示がされないのが問題になります。PHP5では、普通にデータ表示がされましたが、PHP7対応用でソース変更をしてもデータが表示されません。。。どの書き方が間違っているのかが分かりません。。。
※WHERE type !='B' のところでしょうか。。。
アドバイスをお願い致します。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらの質問ですが、どういうエラーメッセージが出ているのか、そのまま **コピー＆ペースト** して頂けませんか？　このままでは回答しようとする方もエラーの再現ができませんので、必要な情報だと思います。質問文の下の「編集」を選び、質問文に直接追記して頂ければと思います。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 手続き型のmysqli は問題無いと思います。データ内容が不明なのでｓｑｌをコマンドラインから実行してエラーやデータが選択されるかを確認すると良いでしょう。変数 $total, $first, $last に期待する値が代入されているのでしょうか？

Comment: `SELECT * FROM NoticeTable WHERE type !='B' ORDER BY serialnum DESC`の部分はPHPではなくてMySQLの部分になるので関係ないと思われます。ソースコード省略されてます？見る限り`$total`に代入されるような処理には見受けられませんが。